# What do 'let' and 'in' mean in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, let

I feel like this seemingly simple and essential thing is completely cryptic to me. What does 'let' expression mean? I have tried to google, but the results are full of concepts that I don't understand.

Here is some code I wrote during a lecture. It identifies if a given string is a palindrome. I don't quite understand where the return keyword is either. Is it the 'in'? What is the scope of this function? I am at a loss.

```
module Main where

isPalindrome :: Text -> Bool
isPalindrome text1 
  = let
    list = toString text1
    backwards = reverse list
    in list == backwards
```

What does 'in' mean, when it comes after 'let'?

I come from learning C#, and functional programming is unknown to me.

Thank you.

Comment: `let` creates one or more name bindings and you need another expression where these bindings are in scope and can be used..

Comment: Yes, in your code snippet the 'return' value (really, the evaluated expression) is the contents of the 'in' block: `list == backwards`. `let` indicates that terms in the expression (list, backwards) have bindings that you can lookup in the `let`.

Comment: This is equivalent to `list == backwards where list = toString text1...` but you might see either format (`let/in` vs `where`) depending on how the author wants the code to be read

Comment: Haskel doesn't have a "return keyword"

Comment: Think of a `let` expression as something similar to a code block in C#. The variables defined after `let` are in scope only for the expression following `in`, just as variables declared inside a code block are only in scope until the end of the block.

Comment: A Haskell `let` expression `let { x1 = e1; …; xn = en } in e` could be emulated in C# with a lambda expression containing a series of `var` declarations and a `return` statement, that is immediately invoked: `(() => { var x1 = e1; …; var xn = en; return e; })()`. The variables are in scope in the expression `e`, and the whole thing evaluates to `e`. One subtle difference is that in Haskell, *any* of the variables can refer to each other, while in C#, each variable can only reference those defined *before* it.

Comment: Haskell functions only return expressions; Where they are called can be replaced with the function's value.

Answer (score 14):

Let's look at an example using `IO`, as that's more like the imperative languages you're used to:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
   let n = 37
   print n
```

Should be easy enough, right? `let n = 37` introduces a local variable called `n`, giving it the value `37`. That variable can then be used like any global definition. This is basically the same as `var n = 37;` or `int n = 37;` in C#.

But Haskell is *not* an imperative language, so what looks like “do this, then do that” is actually just syntactic sugar for something purely functional. In this example, the `do` block desugars to something looking very similar:

```
main = let n = 37
       in print n
```

The difference, and advantage, is that the variable is not introduced *at some point in time* as it were, which means you need to be careful about the exact order in which you do stuff, but rather it is introduced into a concrete *scope*. The scope of a `let`-bound variable includes everything that comes after the `in`, but also anything in the `let`-block itself, meaning you could also have

```
main = let m = n + 2
           n = 37
       in print m
```

(note the “reverse control flow”) or even recursive definitions

```
main = let l = 1 : m
           m = 2 : l
       in print $ take 15 l
```

(the latter will print `[1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1]`)

Comment: Thank you, this helped. The problem is that I don't quite know what I don't know, so it is hard to get started. This clarified things a bit!

Answer (score 14):

A `let`-block allows you to create local variables. The general form is

```
let
  var1 = expression
  var2 = another expression
  var3 = stuff
in
  result expression
```

The result of this is whatever `result expression` is, but you can use `var1`, `var2` and `var3` inside `result expression` (and inside `expression`, `another expression`, and `stuff` as well). You can think of `let` and `in` as being brackets around the bunch of local variables you want to define. And yes, the thing after `in` is what you're returning.